# jQuery blur event not fired for table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a table dynamically using jQuery ajax, the rows of the table has "contenteditable=true", I'm trying to listen on blur event for every cell, so that it triggers a function to update that cell dynamically.
The problem is that the event blur isn't fired at all, I've tried different selectors(table,tbody, and finally the whole document), but all in vain.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css' type="text/css">
        <?php
        include './datatable_include.php';
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                $.ajax({//create an ajax request to load_page.php
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "load_table.php",
                    dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#dataTable').find('tbody').html(response);
                        initDataTable('#dataTable', null);
                    }
                });
            });


            $(document).bind("blur", "td", (function () {
                // this code isn't reached 
                alert("ahoo");

                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var message_status = $("#status");
                var value = $(this).text();
                $.post('update_table.php', "id=" + id + "&" + name + "=" + value, function (data) {
                    if (data != '')
                    {
                        message_status.show();
                        message_status.text(data);
                        //hide the message
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            message_status.hide()
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });


            }));


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="dataTable" width="700px" >
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try `$(document).on('blur' ... `

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use "bind" instead of "on" because of the outdated jQuery version that page uses.

Comment: ooh I didn't even look at that before, you're including jQuery multiple times. Thats not good! and for your unfortune I have no solution then

Comment: Then you may want to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)  It's deprecated now, but available in ancient jQuery versions. If you stick with 1.6.3, that's the way to go. If you continue including both... well, good luck with that.

Comment: @caramba I've removed the multiple includes of jQuery now and updated the code, but still, this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(document).bind("td").blur(function()
 {
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that table td isn't a standard focusable element so you can't blur it.
try to add the tabsindex property to each td

```
<td tabindex="1">focus on me</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

the definition of bind function is as follows:

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )
```

so, you should do:

```
 $('td').bind('blur', function(){
   //event handler statement goes here
 });
```

And as mentioned by @paul roub in the comments above, you should be using `live()` function, as you are creating the `td` elements dynamically.

```
$('td').live('blur', function(){
 //event handler statement goes here
});
```

Comment: `.live()` became deprecated long time ago: http://api.jquery.com/live/ And `.bind()` is outdated. You should use `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: know that. but as mentioned in the comments on the question, jquery version being used on the page is an outdated one.

Comment: I updated the code above, and removed the ancient version of jQuery, unfortunately using on() or the deprecated bind() isn't working either.